# How can I show only free rooms in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I am new to Laravel and doing a hotel booking application. In find room I try to check dates from booking table (`time_from` and `time_to`) to show only free rooms.I  think I have some mistakes in my Controller. I tried using `whereRaw()` but it doesn't work either.

Its my FindRoomsController

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Room;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Validator;

class FindRoomsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if (!Gate::allows('find_room_access')) {
            return abort(401);
        }
        $time_from = $request->input('time_from');
        $time_to = $request->input('time_to');


        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $rooms = Room::with('booking')->whereHas('booking', function ($q) use ($time_from, $time_to) {
                $q->where(function ($q2) use ($time_from, $time_to) {
                    $q2->where('time_from', '>=', $time_to)
                       ->orWhere('time_to', '<=', $time_from);
                });
            })->orWhereDoesntHave('booking')->get();
        } else {
            $rooms = null;
        }

        return view('admin.find_rooms.index', compact('rooms', 'time_from', 'time_to'));
    }
}
```

My find room blade

```php
@if (isset($rooms) && is_null($rooms))
<div class="form-group" style="text-align: center">
    <label>@lang('quickadmin.find-room.no_rooms_found')</label>
</div>
@endif

@foreach ($rooms as $room)
<tr data-entry-id="{{ $room->id }}">
    <td></td>
    <td field-key='room_number'>{{ $room->room_number }}</td>
    <td field-key='floor'>{{ $room->floor }}</td>
    <td field-key='description'>{!! $room->description !!}</td>
    <td field-key='category_id'>{{ $room->category->name or ''}}</td>
    <td field-key='price'>{!! $room->price !!}</td>
    <td>
        @can('booking_create')
        <button class="btn btn-danger">
            <a style="color: #ffffff;" href="{{ route('admin.bookings.create',
            ['room_id' => $room->id,'time_from' => $time_from, 'time_to' => $time_to]) }}">
        {!!trans('quickadmin.find-room.book_room')!!}</a>
    </button>
    @endcan
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Booking table in database

```php
if(! Schema::hasTable('bookings')) {
    Schema::create('bookings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->datetime('time_from')->nullable();
        $table->datetime('time_to')->nullable();
        $table->integer('diff_days')->nullable();
        $table->text('additional_information')->nullable();
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('address')->nullable();
        $table->string('phone')->nullable();
        $table->string('email');
        $table->integer('all_price')->nullable();


        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();

        $table->index(['deleted_at']);
    });
}

Schema::table('bookings', function(Blueprint $table) {
    if (!Schema::hasColumn('bookings', 'room_id')) {
        $table->integer('room_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('room_id', '110461_5a676fa239ffd')->references('id')->on('rooms')->onDelete('cascade');
    }
});
```

Comment: can you paste in your error,

Comment: I don’t have any errors. I find room and create booking , and when i want to create new booking its show me this room again. I want service to check the date and don’t show this room on this dates again

Comment: You code is very confusing. You say with('booking).>whereHas('booking') and at the end you say orWhereDoesntHave('booking'). Suggestion, why don't you give raw query a try? Might be less confusing. Also, what's the second parameter in your room_id foreign key? $table->foreign('room_id', '110461_5a676fa239ffd')